# Inserting dictionary rows to database

Tags: python

`example_table` has id (int) auto increment, json_col (text)

This is the example records from my `example_table` that I want to insert the dictionary rows to

```
+----+----------------------------------------------+
| id |                   json_col                   |
+----+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | {"NO":"1","NIM":"4313010001","NAME":"BENJI"} |
|  2 | {"NO":"2","NIM":"4313010002","NAME":"KENJI"} |
|  3 | {"NO":"3","NIM":"4313010003","NAME":"RYUJI"} |
+----+----------------------------------------------+
```

This is the array of dictionaries that I have in my python script

```
dict_result =
[{'NIM': '4313010013','NAME': 'YUKA','STATUS': 'PASSED'},
 {'NIM': '4313010008','NAME': 'YUKO','STATUS': 'PASSED'},
 {'NIM': '4313010017','NAME': 'YUKI','STATUS': 'PASSED'}]
```

I'm trying to insert each of them into the `example_table` like the example records above. This is what I do, I tried to cast it into a string to perhaps it could pass the row as it is just like the example records above but it raised error saying `ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''NIM': '4313010013', 'NAME': 'YUKA', 'STATUS': 'PASSED'})' at line 1")`

```
for i in dict_result:
    x = str(i)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO example_table (json_col) values ({x})".format(x=x))
```

I have read other questions but in other cases it makes the dictionaries into columns which in my case I want to insert it as it is just like a json. What should I do?

**SOLVED**
With help from comments and added information from Danya02 this line solved the problem

```
for i in dict_hasil:
    x = str(i)
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO example_table (json_col) values ("{x}")""".format(x=x))

conn.commit()
```

Comment: What is the schema of your table?

Comment: example_table has id (int) auto increment, json_col (text)

Comment: Try add double quotes between `{x}`? this might just add that in, not 100% sure. The reason it's not working is because you are needing quotations around the values.

Comment: Hi, writing "{x}" instead of {x} caused `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` in `"{x}"`. Nevermind, I made a mistake, it should also use `"""` or the sql statement. but the rows didnt get into the database tho..

Comment: Do keep in mind that you aren't using JSON here. You're taking the string representation of a `dict`, and that is not necessarily something that can be parsed back into a Python object without using `eval` or similar, and [`eval` is `evil`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/5936187). If you use `json.dumps` and `json.loads` you'll save yourself many problems with reading the data you put into the database back.

Comment: @Danya02 Noted! thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are trying to put your data into the SQL command without quotation marks around it. The immediate issue can be solved by writing `"{x}"` instead of `{x}`.

However, doing it this way is a terrible idea, because it's an [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) waiting to happen. To solve this, you don't put the data that you're trying to insert into your database right in the query string, instead you use query parameters:

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mydata (fieldA, fieldB) VALUES (?, ?)", ("evil", "data") )
```

You are correct that in order to put the dictionary into a database row, you'll need to encode it using JSON or something similar. You can look at other answers to see how to do or, but once you get that you get a string which you can insert into the database as shown above.

Comment: Hi, writing "{x}" instead of {x} caused `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` in `"{x}"`. Nevermind, I made a mistake, it should also use `"""` or the sql statement. but the rows didnt get into the database tho..

Comment: That'll be because your SQL line is itself enclosed in "double quotes". Anyway, you shouldn't even try to make it work this way, because it is a world of pain and insecurity. At the very least, if you decide to use JSON, that uses double quotes too, so it'll cause the same error you're seeing now, except in the SQL code.

Comment: oh I see, but  writing "{x}" instead of {x} caused SyntaxError: invalid syntax in "{x}". Why I choose json is because the columns is always changing and by json I don't need to create ever changing columns, this is a final project from my school and I don't really need to make it secure

Comment: You might be interested in [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/1) then. It is a database that stores its data as JSON documents, so you can have many different objects with different fields in it, so you don't have to decide on a schema beforehand.

Comment: I have solved the problem, I just found out I need to call commit function. Also, It's right to use `"""` for the sql statement plus the  "{x}"

Comment: Okay, I will definitely check it out. Thanks!